# S3 hosted website with Cloudflare returns 404 status code for any non root route

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare

I have an S3 hosted website working well behind Cloudflare with the following:

[image: ss1]

`example.com/` works fine

`example.com/test` also works but the document itself in the network tab is returning 404, naturally, because /test doesn't exist on S3.

This is a problem for SEO, how do I configure Cloudflare to treat 404s as 200s?

In Cloudfront I usually do this:

[image: ss2]

But I can find no corresponding configuration in Cloudflare. Will this have to be done in a Cloudflare worker? What did people do before Workers existed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out people just didn't host on S3 with Cloudflare before workers, and if they did, they didn't care/notice that their routes would return 404.

Anyway, this is the solution with Cloudflare workers to force the return code of 200:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(fetchAndApply(event.request))
})

async function fetchAndApply(request) {
  let originalResponse = await fetch(request)

  const contentType = originalResponse.headers.get("Content-Type")

  // Only bother with index pages (not assets)
  if (contentType && contentType.includes("text/html")) {

    // Force 404's from S3 to return as 200 to prevent Google indexing issues
    let response = new Response(originalResponse.body, {
        ...originalResponse,
        status: 200, 
        statusText: 'OK'
      }
    )

    // Don't cache index.html
    response.headers.set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0')

    return response
  }

  return originalResponse
}
```